# how to change a label template using twig inheritance in symfony2

Tags: symfony, inheritance, label, twig

Using Symfony2.3.4 with Twig.

Say I´m trying to add, for example, a colon (:) and, if **required**, an asterisk (*) to every label of every field in a form generated by Symfony2's CRUD. For this I'm using a twig template to inherit Symfony2's main template **form_div_layout.html.twig**.

So far:

```
//config.yml  
twig:
    form:
        resources:
        - ::my_form_layout.html.twig

//my_form_layout.html.twig
{% block form_label %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if label is not sameas(false) %}
            ...
            {% set asterisk = '<sup><i title="Campo obligatorio" 
            class="glyphicon-asterisk" style="color: red; font-size: 
            8px"></i></sup>' %}
            <label {% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} 
            {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>
            {{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}: {% if required %}
            {{ asterisk|raw }} {% endif %}
            </label>
            ...
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_label %}
```

Problem is this way when I render, for example, a choice-type field for selecting the sex of a person, with **expanded** and **required** set to **TRUE**, the colon (:) and the asterisk (*) appear next to the word **Sex** *AND* the words **Male** and **Female** as well.

How can I make the template differenciate between the parent and the two children, so the colon and the asterisk appear only after the word **Sex**.

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I've done something similar. Modify the 'choice_widget_expanded' block a bit in your custom form layout:

```
// update this row: {{ form_label(child) }}
{{ form_label(child, child, {'exclude_additions': 'true'}) }}
```

And update your 'form_label' to check whether this value is defined:

```
{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}{% if exclude_additions is not defined %}: {% if required %}
{{ asterisk|raw }} {% endif %} {% endif %}
```

Comment: error on step 1: **Variable "child_label" does not exist in ::my_form_layout.html.twig at line 9**. just in case: "my_form_layout.html.twig" is the template I use to inherit.

Comment: **{{ form_label(child, child, {'exclude_additions': 'true'}) }}** did it, thanx.

Comment: roger that - seems that my second parameter was indeed invalid and I just didn't have twig error reporting on. In this case the second parameter doesn't seem to matter - as long as you don't give any string values that is - so null might be a more intuitive value to pass (just assuming that it will work as well - didn't actually check that). Updated my answer in any way to the working format.